Help Needed: ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND in Solana TypeScript Project
I’m currently working on a TypeScript project using the Solana Web3.js library and encountered the following error when trying to run my script:
PS D:\Code\ts> npx esrun t1.ts
node:internal/process/esm_loader:34
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\Code\ts\node_modules\.bin\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js' imported from D:\Code\ts\node_modules\.bin\esrun-1730469336690.tmp.mjs
Did you mean to import "../@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js"?
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:264:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:924:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1148:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  url: 'file:///D:/Code/ts/node_modules/.bin/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js'
}

Node.js v21.7.3

Code Snippet:
import {
  Connection,
  Transaction,
  SystemProgram,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  PublicKey,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
require('dotenv').config();
import { getKeypairFromEnvironment } from "@solana-developers/helpers";
 
const suppliedToPubkey = process.argv[2] || null;
 
if (!suppliedToPubkey) {
  console.log(`Please provide a public key to send to`);
  process.exit(1);
}
 
const senderKeypair = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");
 
console.log(`suppliedToPubkey: ${suppliedToPubkey}`);
 
const toPubkey = new PublicKey(suppliedToPubkey);
 
const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");
 
console.log(
  `✅ Loaded our own keypair, the destination public key, and connected to Solana`,
);
const transaction = new Transaction();
 
const LAMPORTS_TO_SEND = 5000;
 
const sendSolInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
  fromPubkey: senderKeypair.publicKey,
  toPubkey,
  lamports: LAMPORTS_TO_SEND,
});
 
transaction.add(sendSolInstruction);
 
const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
  senderKeypair,
]);
 
console.log(
  ` Finished! Sent ${LAMPORTS_TO_SEND} to the address ${toPubkey}. `,
);
console.log(`Transaction signature is ${signature}!`);```


do you have the dev dependencies installed? pnpm install

Yes, I have the necessary dependencies installed. I used the following command: npm install typescript @solana/web3.js esrun @solana-developers/helpers
If there are any additional dependencies or steps I might have missed, please let me know. Thank you!

is this a repo that you can share?

sure,https://github.com/eclouder/ts

tried it on WSL and it worked. Is it possible to switch to that?
